# Netty SslHandler not working for own root certificate

Tags: java, ssl, netty

I am using Netty 4.1.25. I create a `X509Certificate` from a `pem` file in my code. Using that certificate, I setup the SslHandler like this:

```
SslContext context = SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager( certificate ).build();
pipeline.addLast( "ssl", context.newHandler( socketChannel.alloc() ) );
```

When the certificate is the exact certificate that is on the server (The server is an IoT device, but probably does not matter), this works fine.

However, when I create an own root certificate and:

- the server has a certificate that trusts the root certificate
- the Netty app uses the root certificate

Then I get this exception:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:459) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:647) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:547) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:501) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:461) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:259) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:642) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:461) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:361) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1065) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1052) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:999) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1435) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1343) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1177) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1221) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:290) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:321) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:279) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:620) ~[na:na]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380) ~[na:na]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

To test, I also used the option of SslContextBuilder to use a `TrustManagerFactory` instead of the certificate directly:

```
TrustManagerFactory factory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
factory.init(certificateService.getKeyStore());
SslContext context = SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager(factory).build();
```

This however gives the same problem.

Interestingly, this IoT device also has a web interface that uses the same certificate. When I open this URL using that same `TrustManagerFactory`, this works without issues:

```
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
sc.init(null, factory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
URL url = new URL("https://10.65.101.155");
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
```

Using `urlConnection` I can print the contents of the webpage and see the certificate information.

I already ran with `-Djava.security.debug=all`, but that seems to be a lot of info that I don't quite understand I am afraid.

Why does it work via `URL`, but not via Netty using the same `TrustManagerFactory` ? Is there anything I can do on Netty side to further debug this? Is there an option to print the certificate that Netty receives from the server?

Comment: Did you try to use `SslContext.newHandler(ByteBufAllocator alloc, String peerHost, int peerPort)` ?

Comment: @NormanMaurer Yes, same result unfortunately.

Comment: @NormanMaurer See answer now, was not a Netty issue in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out what was wrong. The IoT device uses [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) for the certificate of the web interface, but [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/) for the certificate that Netty uses for communication.

I managed to see this using `openssl` CLI:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect 10.65.101.155:6000
```

The response of this command did not show the proper certificate chain while doing the same command with port `443` instead of `6000` did show the good chain of trust.

It seems that `stunnel` requires the `.pem` file to contain a concatenation of the "root" and the "end-entity" certificate `.pem` files in 1 single file (Thanks to https://serverfault.com/a/254804/209813).

After changing the IoT device like this, the Netty communication is also ok now.